# Why can't std::ranges::views::filter take std::isupper as argument?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <ranges>

constexpr inline auto filter_upper = std::views::filter(::isupper);
```

The new range adaptors `filter_upper` works fine with global old c-function `::isupper`, but if I replace with `std::isupper`, I got this compiler error:

```
<source>:4:69: error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<std::ranges::views::<lambda(_Range&&, _Pred&&)> >) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
    4 | constexpr inline auto filter_upper = std::views::filter(std::isupper);
      |                                                                     ^
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:1102:4: note: candidate: 'constexpr auto std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<_Callable>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {}; _Callable = std::ranges::views::<lambda(_Range&&, _Pred&&)>]'
 1102 |    operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
      |    ^~~~~~~~
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There appear to be several overloads of `isupper` in the `std` namespace and the compiler doesn't know which one to pick. If you use `static_cast<int (*)(int)>(std::isupper)` it compiles.

Anyway, I believe that you are not allowed to use the address of a `std` function, so better use a lambda:

```
constexpr inline auto filter_upper = std::views::filter([](unsigned char c) { return std::isupper(c); });
```

Comment: or `[](auto c) { return std::isupper(c); }` to reify the overload set

Comment: I think this needs to be `[](unsigned char c) { return std::isupper(c); }` to be correct.

Comment: The lambda also fixes the trouble with negative `char` values.

Comment: But don't use a cast where an implicit conversion is allowed.